# Select all records where the id is not in another table using Cakephp 2.x

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

hello I want to implement `OR` condition in my query which will be to fetch all records from another table where id is not present `OR` fetch records which have been inserted in last 24 hours.

This query is getting me results of last 24Hours

```
        $this->Behaviors->attach('Containable');
        return $this->find('all', array(

            'contain' => array(
              'User','UserInfo','QuestionAndTopic.Topic','UpVoteQuestion','Answer'

            ),
             'conditions' => array(
                'Question.created >=' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-24 hour'))

            ),

            'order' => 'Question.question_id DESC',
            'recursive' => 0
        ));
```

I want to do Something like this

```
$this->Behaviors->attach('Containable');
return $this->find('all', array(

    'contain' => array(
      'User','UserInfo','QuestionAndTopic.Topic','UpVoteQuestion','Answer'

    ),
     'conditions' => array(
         'OR' => array(
    array( 'Question.created >=' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-24 hour'))),
    array('Question.question_id NOT IN ' => 'Answers'),// get results where question id is not present in answers table as foreign key
)



    ),

    'order' => 'Question.question_id DESC',
    'recursive' => 0
));
```

I hope you understand my question

Comment: Read this: https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#complex-find-conditions

Comment: @Kenyanke Hello thank you very much for sharing it. I have understood most of the part but One thing i want to know is how can I check data in table. here 
array('Question.question_id NOT IN ' => 'Answers'),

Comment: How is your query suppose to know that question_id exists in Answers?

Comment: @Kenyanke I am sorry I am not really good in this. All I want is that to fetch all the questions from questions tables But those questions(question_id) shouldn't be present in answers table

Comment: If you are unsure, just use a query(), I hope you are familiar with SQL, if you are not, I recommend you learning instead of not understanding your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways you can do this.

1)
You can use a left join and check where there are no answers.

In SQL:

```
select * 
from questions 
left join answers on questions.id = answers.question_id
where answers.id is null;
```

In CakePHP:

```
$this->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'User','UserInfo','QuestionAndTopic.Topic','UpVoteQuestion','Answer'
    ),
   'conditions' => array(
       'OR' => array(
           array( 'Question.created >=' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-24 hour'))),
           array('Answer.id is null'),// get results where question id is not present in answers table as foreign key
       )
    ),
    'order' => 'Question.question_id DESC',
    'recursive' => 0
));
```

2)

You can use a subquery to load the list of question IDs in the answers table, and use a basic `not in` to get the complementary set.

In SQL:

```
select * from questions where id not in (select distinct question_id from answers);
```

In CakePHP:

Subqueries in cakephp are a bit complicated. You first have to set up the subquery and then call that in the query. See https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#sub-queries

I've never tried using a subquery in the conditions, but I think this should work.

```
$db = $this->getDataSource();
$subquery = $db->buildStatement(
    array(
        'table' => 'answers',
        'alias' => 'Answer',
        'fields' => 'question_id'
    ),
    $this
);
$this->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'User','UserInfo','QuestionAndTopic.Topic','UpVoteQuestion','Answer'
    ),
   'conditions' => array(
       'OR' => array(
           array( 'Question.created >=' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-24 hour'))),
           array('Question.question_id NOT IN ' => '($subquery)'),// get results where question id is not present in answers table as foreign key
       )
    ),
    'order' => 'Question.question_id DESC',
    'recursive' => 0
));
```